# Site not working in IE 10 IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

My website is not loading javascript/css files in ie10, 11. I am using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/utils.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/mod-homepage-video-player.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.home.min.js"></script>
```

but its not working in ie and giving me this error

[image]

Please help

**Update**

```
<html><head><title></title><!-- <script language="javascript">window.location.replace("//abc.com/images/hp_elitebook.png");</script> --></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: It is ironic because .net is framework of microsoft and browsers also

Comment: @HddnTHA I am not getting your point. please explain.

Comment: hit some of those js/css files directly in your browser, see what's coming across. could be you've got somethign on your server's inserting stuff into the files, making them "not-js", and "not-css".

Comment: No need for explaination. Because it is just a comment. I am not familiar of .net and ie browsers and i dont have enough knowledge to answer your question. But may be you should change your question tag to mime types; because errors about mime types.

Comment: Are you running any JavaScript preprocessing that you've not told usl  about?

Comment: I've also noticed that one of the errors is from the modernizr lib,  but its call is not in the code snippet. Can we see all of the code?

Comment: Did your site works on other browsers ?

Comment: hi guys. I find something.  for http, it works fine but for https its not working. server is responding this message. check update